# Looking for convenient way to define lexically scoped aliases for functions

Tags: elisp

I'm looking for the closest equivalent (both typographically and semantically) to what the following would do if functions in Elisp were "first-class":

```
(let ((f function-with-very-long-name))
     (progn
           ...
           (f ...)   ;; evaluates to (function-with-very-long-name ...)
           ...
    )
)
```

IOW, I'm looking for a convenient way to define *lexically scoped aliases* for functions.

The closest I've found involves binding the aliasing symbol (`f` in the example above) to a `lambda` that in turn calls the aliased function.  I find this approach typographically cumbersome.  (It negates whatever typographic simplification the rest of the code may have gained from the aliasing.)

Is there anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `funcall` for this. For example, the `let` below passes 21 to `a-function-with-an-extremely-long-name`, which doubles it and returns 42:

```
(defun a-function-with-an-extremely-long-name (i) (* 2 i))

(let ((f 'a-function-with-an-extremely-long-name))
  (funcall f 21))
```

Comment: That's only lexically-scoped if you take additional steps to enable lexical scope in general in the containing library. By default `f` would have dynamic scope. (It's not a factor in the code shown here, but as the question was explicit about lexical scope, it's a relevant point.)

Comment: True, but to me the question seemed focused mostly on the convenience of using shorter names for calling certain functions, and not so much on scoping. I suppose I could have requested a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to use `cl-flet` or `cl-labels` (the exact names may depend on which version of Emacs you are using, due to the great cl-* renaming.  You can also use `cl-letf` with `(symbol-function 'symbol)` if you prefer, though I think that's needlessly obscure.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind rewriting the snippet in my original post using one of the functions you mentioned?

Comment: If you don't know the arguments you can just use apply.  Like `(cl-flet ((f (&rest args) (apply #'function-with-long-name args))) (f ...))`